# Find the image of the first square $\Re z>0$, $\Im z>0$ in the mapping $w=\sqrt{\ln\left ( z^2+1 \right )}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the image of the first square $\Re z>0$, $\Im z>0$ in the mapping $w=\sqrt{\ln\left ( z^2+1 \right )}$

My attempt:
$$z=x+iy\wedge x,y>0\Rightarrow z^2+1=\left ( x^2-y^2+1 \right )+2xyi\Rightarrow $$
$$\Rightarrow \ln \left ( z^2+1 \right )=\ln \left ( x^2-y^2+1 \right )+i\arctan \left ( \frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2+1} \right )$$
$$w=\sqrt{\ln \left ( z^2+1 \right )}=\sqrt{\ln \left ( x^2-y^2+1 \right )}+\frac{i}{2}\arctan \left ( \frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2+1} \right )$$

Did I find $w$ correctly? And the next question, how do I find the image of the first square?

Comment: Correct is: $w=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2} i \arg \left(\log \left(1+(x+i y)^2\right)\right)} \sqrt[4]{\log ^2\left(x^4+2 x^2 \left(y^2+1\right)+\left(y^2-1\right)^2\right)+4 \arg \left(1+(x+i y)^2\right)^2}}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: You have a failure in $ln(z^2+1)$:
$$\ln\left(\left(x+I\cdot y\right)^{2}+1\right)=\frac{\ln\! \left(\left(x^{2}-y^{2}+1\right)^{2}+4 x^{2} y^{2}\right)}{2}+\mathrm{i} \arctan(2 x y,x^{2}-y^{2}+1)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your solution, finding $\ln (z^2+1)$ from $z^2+1$ has a problem, since in general $\arg(x+iy)\ne \tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}$. As an example, for $z=-1+i$ we have $\arg(z)=\frac{3\pi}{4}\ne \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{-1}=-\frac{\pi}{4}$.

A simpler solution exists due to the simplicity of the domain of mapping. We apply the following mappings to $A_1=\{z:\Re\{z\}>0,\Im\{z\}>0\}$ consequently
$$
A_1
\overset{z\to z^2}{\implies} A_2
\overset{z\to 1+z}{\implies} A_3
\overset{z\to \ln z}{\implies} A_4
\overset{z\to \sqrt z}{\implies} A_5.
$$
Therefore, $A_5$ is the range of $A_1$ under the mapping $\sqrt{\ln{(1+z^2)}}$.

Note that $A_1=\{r\exp(i\theta):r>0,0<\theta<\pi/2\}$. Therefore $A_2=\{r\exp(i\theta):r>0,0<\theta<\pi\}$ which is the complex upper half-plane. The mapping $z\to 1+z$ is a translation, therefore $A_3=A_2$. For $A_4$ we have
$$
A_4=\{\ln r+i\theta:r>0,0<\theta<\pi\}=\{x+iy:x\in \Bbb R,0<y<\pi\},
$$
which is a horizontal strip of width $\pi$ right above the real line. Finally,
$$
A_5=\{x+iy:x>0,0<y<\frac{\pi}{2x}\}.
$$

Comment: Small correction: I think $A_5$ should be $\{x+iy:x>0,0<y<\frac{\pi}{2x}\}$.

Comment: The border $r=1/\sin\theta$ of $A_4$ is converted into $$w=\sqrt{r}\exp(i\theta/2)=\frac{\cos\theta/2+i\sin\theta/2}{\sqrt{\sin\theta}}=\sqrt{0.5\cot \theta}+i\sqrt{0.5\tan \theta}.$$Therefore$$\Re\{w\}\Im\{w\}=0.5.$$

Comment: The border of $A_4$ is $y=\pi$, which corresponds to $r=\pi/\sin \theta$.

Comment: That's correct. Thanks.